# Removing GUI of Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: raspbian, pi-b+

I would like to ask how to open a Raspberry Pi in terminal mode only? Right now i want my Raspberry Pi to just autorun a Python script after plugging the power supply. Thanks for the answers guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line open the raspi-config script:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Using your up down arrows select option 3:

**Boot Options**

Then select Option 1:

**Desktop/CLI**

Select either option 1 or 2:

**Console** or **Console Autologin**

Then Click (use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key):

**OK**

Finally click:

**Finish**

and reboot to test.

These settings are also available from the GUI preferences menu.

Comment: if my raspberry disable the GUI, how can i go back to GUI?

Comment: The same way except you choose desktop or desktop autologin instead of console.

Comment: sir can i ask how can i determine my Raspberry Pi B+ if its Raspbian Wheezy or Raspbian Jessie?

Comment: Comments arfe not for asking unrelated questions. If you can't finfd the answer by searching either google or this site then ask a new question.